# Dynamic page length for Vaadin Table with big tables

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

My goal: the Vaadin Table should take 100% height of the parent element (HorizontalLayout).

I do know that I could set the page length to 0, but as my table is really long, I would like to keep the lazy loading behavior. Is there a way to make Vaadin determin the page length dynamically?

**Update**: I found a hack with

```
.v-table-body {
    height: calc(100% - #{($v-table-row-height + 3 * $v-table-border-width)}) !important;
  }
```

in SCSS, which sets the height correctly. However, besides the fact that using  `!important` is kind of disturbing here, the lazy also still shows line numbers in 15 rows step, i.e. `1-15...`.

Comment: What's the problem with `table.setHeight("100%")`?

Comment: the problem is, that it does not set the height to 100% unless you have page length = 0

Comment: The lazy loading mechanism is not affected by `setPageLength()`. It's only a visual setting. `setCacheRate()` on the hand other affects your cache.

Comment: "The amount of cached rows will be cacheRate multiplied with pageLength", says spec. I.e. if I understand it correctly, this would result in the table loading everything when setting the page length to 0....

Comment: You are right. `setPageLength()` does affect the table cache. I looked that up too. Sorry for the misleading comment.

Answer (score 0):

What I found out is: you can just write

```
table.setSizeFull();
horizontalLayout.addComponent(table);
```

The table is larger now and shows more Objects depending on your screen size. But still the table works with a cache. You can see also in the network tab in Chrome's developer tools that not all elements are send but only a fraction of it (visible rows + cached ones). By debugging I found out that the pageLength member of the table changed according to the number of visible elements.

You don't need to set the page length and you don't need your CSS hack.